# dynamic variable name and multiple condition in function in r

Tags: r, function

I want to create a function with dynamic variables ( `var1, var2, var3 and var4`) and dynamic conditions. Here is the sample function

```
dta = data.frame(var1 = c(1:8),
                 var2 = c(rep("AA",4),rep("BB",4)),
                 var3 = rep(c("C","D"),4),
                 var4 = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1))

mean(dta$var1[dta$var2 == "AA" & dta$var3 == "C" & dta$var4 == 1] 
            - dta$var1[dta$var2 == "AA" & dta$var3 == "C" & dta$var4 == 0],na.rm = T)
```

If I want to create a function like this

```
sample_fun = function(dta,var1 = "var1",var2 == "var2,var2_cond = "AA",var3_cond = "C",var4_cond = 1){
  mean(dta$var1[dta$var2 == var2_cond & dta$var3 == var3_cond & dta$var4 == 1] 
       - dta$var1[dta$var2 == var2_cond & dta$var3 == var3_cond & dta$var4 == 0],na.rm = T)
  
}
```

How should I do that? using `dplyr` is also fine with me.

My particular concern is the dynamic of `var1`. How should do it all dynamic variables (`var1, var2, var3` and `var4`) together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `[[` to extract column as vector. Also I use `with` to avoid writing `data$` everytime.

```
sample_fun = function(dta, var = 'var1', var2_var = "var2", var2_cond = "AA", var3_cond = "C"){
  
  with(dta, mean(dta[[var]][dta[[var2_var]] == var2_cond & 
                  var3 == var3_cond & var4 == 1] - 
                  dta[[var]][dta[[var2_var]] == var2_cond & var3 == var3_cond & 
                  var4 == 0],na.rm = TRUE))
}

sample_fun(dta)
#[1] -2

sample_fun(dta, 'var4',var2_var = "var2", var2_cond = 'BB', var3_cond = 'D')
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I edited the questions. Actually, my biggest concern is the dynamic variable of var1. How can I change the var1 variable with others?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the requirement. Would you be able to give couple of example inputs to your function and show expected output based on that?

Comment: If I want to change var1 to var5, var6, etc let's say how should I create the function?

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you. If I var2 is also a dynamic one, how should I do it? Thank you in advance

Comment: sample_fun = function(dta, var = 'var1', var2_cond = "AA",var3_cond = "C"){

 with(dta, mean(dta[[var]][dta[[var2]][== var2_cond & var3 == var3_cond & var4 == 1] - 
    dta[[var]][dta[[var2]][== var2_cond & var3 == var3_cond & var4 == 0],na.rm = TRUE))
}

Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by making `var2` dynamic? `var2_cond` and `var3_cond` are used to filter specific values from `var2` and `var3` respectively. `var` is dynamic to calculate corresponding mean from that variable.

Comment: if I want to many variables and want to have var2_2 == var2_cond_2 instead of var2 == var2_cond,
does this work?
with(dta, mean(dta[[var]][dta[[var2_2]] == var2_cond_2& var3 == var3_cond & var4 == 1] - 
dta[[var2_2]] == var2_cond_2 & var3 == var3_cond & var4 == 0],na.rm = TRUE))
}

Comment: Whatever is dynamic you need to pass it as separate argument. See updated answer.